# gcc symbol resolution shadowing

Tags: gcc, linker, libc, crt, atexit

I'm trying to add some custom code to our internal libc related to atexit handling.

In our libc we define this because we link to custom CRT files and don't use GCC's which defines this.

```
void *__dso_handle __attribute__((__visibility__("hidden"),__weak__)) = &__dso_handle;
```

GCC also adds this to binaries when linking them.

In the libc is the function atexit which just calls

```
int atexit(void (*func)(void))
{
    return __cxa_atexit((void (*)(void*))func, NULL, __dso_handle);
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the _dso_handle value used is the local one from libc when I'd like to make it dynamically fetch the one from the module that calls atexit() at runtime so that the proper dso is registered with the atexit function.

I checked attributes and I found nothing that could help there.

Note that unlike glibc, atexit is kept in the dynamic version of libc to preserve backwards compatibility with older binaries.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue I'm facing is that the _dso_handle value used is the local one from libc when I'd like to make it dynamically fetch the one from the module that calls atexit() at runtime

Your module can call `__cxa_atexit` instead, and pass in whatever `dso_handle` you desire.